# Detect Failure or Error of Junit Test in @After method

Tags: java, junit

Is there a way in JUnit to detect within an @After annotated method if there was a test failure or error in the test case?

One **ugly** solution would be something like that:

```
boolean withoutFailure = false;

@Test
void test() {
  ...
  asserts...
  withoutFailure = true;
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
   if(!withoutFailuere) {
      this.dontReuseTestenvironmentForNextTest();
   }
}
```

This is ugly because one need to take care of the "infrastructure" (withoutFailure flag) in the test code.

I hope that there is something where I can get the test status in the @After method!?

Comment: Isn't your `@Before` method taking care of ensuring that the environment is setup correctly for every test?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: Yes and no: I am doing Tests with Selemium2/Webdriver, and I want to reuse the driver. But I only want to reuse then if the test before was without any error.

Comment: Ah ok, my current problem. I'm trying to avoid the flag. Hope to see some other answer. I'll post mine if I encounter a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are lucky enough to be using JUnit 4.9 or later, [`TestWatcher`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) will do exactly what you want.

Share and Enjoy!

Comment: Since this post TestWatchman is now deprecated, TestWatcher is the new class.

Comment: This doesn't work with JUnit 4.12 and Arquillian 1.1.10, because the TestWatcher gets notified of failure too late - after the `@After` method is executed.

Comment: According to https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/906 this is the intended behavior, so I believe this answer, while useful, to be wrongly accepted - it doesn't achieve the goal stated in the question.

Comment: @Gustave: the answer is not wrong. It is just true what the comments about have already told you. So if you really need to use AfterMethods instead of Rules, then it is not enough to use `TestWatcher` out the box. You will need to write your own little `TestWatcher` based framework: Have a look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44000067/280244

Answer (score 7):

I extend dsaff's answer to solve the problem that a `TestRule` can not execute some code snipped between the execution of the test-method and the after-method. So with a simple `MethodRule` one can not use this rule to provide a success flag that is use in the `@After` annotated methods.

My idea is a hack! Anyway, it is to use a `TestRule` (extends `TestWatcher`). A `TestRule` will get knowledge about failed or success of a test. My `TestRule` will then scan the class for all Methods annotated with my new `AfterHack` annotations and invoke that methods with a success flag.

---

`AfterHack` annotation

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;    
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface AfterHack {}
```

`AfterHackRule`

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class AfterHackRule extends TestWatcher {

    private Object testClassInstance;
    public AfterHackRule(final Object testClassInstance) {
        this.testClassInstance = testClassInstance;
    }

    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        invokeAfterHackMethods(true);
    }

    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        invokeAfterHackMethods(false);
    }

    public void invokeAfterHackMethods(boolean successFlag) {
        for (Method afterHackMethod :
                    this.getAfterHackMethods(this.testClassInstance.getClass())) {
            try {
                afterHackMethod.invoke(this.testClassInstance, successFlag);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                     | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("error while invoking afterHackMethod " 
                          + afterHackMethod);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Method> getAfterHackMethods(Class<?> testClass) {
        List<Method> results = new ArrayList<>();            
        for (Method method : testClass.getMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(AfterHack.class)) {
                results.add(method);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
public class DemoTest {

    @Rule
    public AfterHackRule afterHackRule = new AfterHackRule(this);

    @AfterHack
    public void after(boolean success) { 
        System.out.println("afterHack:" + success);
    }

    @Test
    public void demofails() {
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @Test
    public void demoSucceeds() {}
}
```

---

BTW:

- 1) Hopefully there is a better solution in Junit5
- 2) The better way is to use the TestWatcher Rule instead of the @Before and @After Method at all (that is the way I read dsaff's answer)

@see

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any easy or elegant way to detect the failure of a Junit test in an @After method.

If it is possible to use a TestRule instead of an @After method, one possibility to do it is using two chained TestRules, using a TestWatcher as the inner rule.

Example:

```
    package org.example;

    import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

    import org.junit.Rule;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.rules.ExternalResource;
    import org.junit.rules.RuleChain;
    import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
    import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
    import org.junit.runner.Description;

    public class ExampleTest {

      private String name = "";
      private boolean failed;

      @Rule
      public TestRule afterWithFailedInformation = RuleChain
        .outerRule(new ExternalResource(){
          @Override
          protected void after() {
            System.out.println("Test "+name+" "+(failed?"failed":"finished")+".");
          }      
        })
        .around(new TestWatcher(){
          @Override
          protected void finished(Description description) {
            name = description.getDisplayName();
          }
          @Override
          protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            failed = true;
          }      
        })
      ;

      @Test
      public void testSomething(){
        fail();
      }

      @Test
      public void testSomethingElse(){
      }

    }
```

Comment: But when I am able to use an TestRule instead of @After, then I can use the TestRule and do not need the `RuleChain` - or did i missed something?

Comment: The RuleChain... part constructs a new TestRule by "concatenating" two rules together (TestWatcher and ExternalResource). You could specify those rules independantly, but than it could happen that the after() method is executed before failed(). The System.out.println() part is what you would put in a corresponding @After method.

Comment: What I do not understand is: why should I not simply use the `TestWatcher` it runs after the test and has a method for `succeeded` and one for `failed`?

Comment: Matter of taste. You could do that, but you would somehow contradict the Javadoc of TestWatcher that says "TestWatcher is a base class for Rules that take note of the testing action, without modifying it." May be some test framework relies on that Javadoc. And it has no "after" method.

Comment: A typical use case is closing external resources, so you might want to use some subclass of ExternalResource.