# Will junit rules solve my issue?

Tags: selenium, ant, junit

I have a set of selenium tests. Currently these are run through a junit ant tool that generates a nice pretty report at the end. I need a similar report but with additional customized information.

My question is : When a junit test reaches the @After part, does it know whether the test that just ran passed or failed, or how long it took to complete etc If it does then I can modify my @after to write a line to a simplified html file, which seems like an easier option than trying to modify the ant tools reporting functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981903/detect-failure-or-error-of-junit-test-in-after-method).  You can use [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) to catch the information about the test status and then process is as you like.