# How to capture Junit test case run result

Tags: java, junit

I would like to call some methods on the basis of test case run result. My example code snippet is below

```
testrun ()
{
String Expected, Actual;
assertEquals(Expected, Actual);

}
```

So, in the above example, if the values of variables Expected and Actual are same, then the test case will pass, else it will fail.

I would like to capture the pass/fail and based upon it to perform some certain actions.
I am new to Junit and looking for some help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Failure or Error of Junit Test in @After method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981903/detect-failure-or-error-of-junit-test-in-after-method)

Comment: You can find basic information about JUnit here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/ .

Comment: I don't really see the point of checking the test result, what would you want to do in that case other than fixing the code?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth well there is , I use testrail as my test management application. if my test case passes i call an API to mark the test case passed or failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6985438/1621402), you can use a [TestWatcher](http://junit.org/apidocs/index.html?org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html), like this:

```
public class WatchTest {
    @Rule
    public TestRule watcher = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            System.out.println("Pass!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            System.out.println("Fail!");
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void testRun() throws Exception {
        String expected = "asd";
        String actual = "qwert";

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For TestNG (not for JUnit)**

Add this code to your test class (see @AfterMethod annotation):

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult r) {
    if(r.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        System.out.println(r.getMethod().getMethodName()+ " is failed");
        // any more report action what you need  
    } else {
        System.out.println(r.getMethod().getMethodName()+ " is OK");
        // any more report action what you need  
    }     
}
```

**How to do it without JUnit/TestNG**

You can wrap your test-body into try-catch and do something (call to TestRail etc.) before the test finished. Example (you can run it to see results in Output Panel, it's working):

```
public class SomeTest {

    protected String methodName;

    public void setMethodName(Class cl, Exception ex) {
        methodName = cl.getName() + "." + ex.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() + "()";        
    }

    public int half(Integer v) {
        return v/2;
    }

    @Test
    public void willFailed() throws Exception {
        setMethodName(this.getClass(), new Exception());
        try {
            assertEquals(half(null), 2);              
            System.out.println("Report about good result in " + methodName);
            // any more report action what you need  
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Report about bug in " + methodName); // Report before crash
            // any more report action what you need  
            throw new Exception(ex); // booom
        }          
    }   

    @Test
    public void willPassed() throws Exception {
        setMethodName(this.getClass(), new Exception());
        try {            
            assertEquals(half(2), 1);
            System.out.println("Report about good result in " + methodName);
            // any more report action what you need  
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Report about bug in " + methodName); // Report before crash
            // any more report action what you need  
            throw new Exception(ex); // booom
        }          
    }   

}
```